# How to run a script file

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, directory-structure

Using Mint Linux 19 here.

I have a script file called `test.sh`. This script-file is located in a path e.g. `/home/shyam/Mi A1/tissot`, and I use it to flash Android system on my phone. The script contain command lines like:

```
fastboot $* flash modem_a `dirname $0`/images/modem.img
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo "Flash modem_a error"; exit 1; fi
fastboot $* flash modem_b `dirname $0`/images/modem.img
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then echo "Flash modem_b error"; exit 1; fi.....
```

The `images` folder mentioned in these commands is located in a separate folder in the same folder `tissot` and has files such as `modem.img` in the snippet above

- `adb` and `fastboot` runs fine with the android device
- `Test.sh` is executable as explained in Isiah's answer in [How do I run .sh files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files)

I tried to run the script by double clicking on the file and selecting *run in terminal*, but it did not work, nothing is flashed on in my phone and the terminal window banished in a jiffy.

**Question**

How do I run this file and see the output similar to "Target reported size...OKAY"

I am sure that the path in the test file does not match but I don't know how to fix that as also to see the output as explained for each line

Comment: Downvoting is fine but explaining reasons helps, which I understand is per SE culture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal application (you can find it in the application menu) and run:

```
cd /home/shyam/Mi\ A1/tissot
chmod u+x test.sh
./test.sh
```

Each line is a command.

Keep in mind that running application found on the internet can be dangerous. Before doing this you should learn how to use the linux shell ( this is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell) ) and understand what the program does.

Comment: +1. Thanks for response. will test it. 1. Meanwhile `Mi**\** A1` - the backslash I suppose is to indicate the space ? 2. It is not a random file from internet. It is from the OEM and is not questionable at all . I simplified names 3. Yes, I should learn the right way but then I find it easier to learn and use what I need to get the job done (avoiding windows drivers and other issues )

Comment: yes the backslash is used to indicate the space.

Comment: Ok. I was able to "dry run" . Didn't want to test live on phone as I had already flashed it manually line by line earlier in day and set up the device . So in good faith accepting the answer . If you don't mind, what does *fi* at the end of each line in the snippet mean?

Comment: Never mind .[Got the meaning of fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010830/bash-whats-the-use-of-fi)